Fit a disk/circle to 3D points
I'm trying to fit a disk/circle to 3D points captured by a 3D LIDAR, knowing the radius of the disk/circle. I'm interested in finding the center of the disk $(x_c,y_c,z_c)$. The points are distributed on the surface of the disk, and not on the circumference of the disk/circle (see front view and side view ).
Most online resources suggest creating a local coordinate system based on the plane that these points lie on, projecting the points onto that plane, fitting a 2D circle, and then back-projecting the center to 3D. However, I'm unsure if this method will work in my case since the points are not on the circumference.
What is the best approach to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated!
Here is the sample data disk.ply

Do you have numerical data?

Sure. Just added the ply of the 3D points. The radius of the disk i am trying to fit is 10cm.

To have an acceptable approximation to the center, if the points are uniformly spread, the barycenter works well. The data given doesn't involve statistics, scale factors or propagation issues. Follows a MATHEMATICA script which shows that the barycenter location is satisfactory. In yellow the adjusting plane in red a possible circle, and in blue the data. The barycenter is depicted in black.
data = {{2.574`, -1.411`, 0.052`}, {2.573`, -1.421`, 0.052`}, {2.555`, -1.422`, 0.051`}, 
{2.54`, -1.424`, 0.051`}, {2.539`, -1.434`, 0.051`}, {2.527`, -1.438`, 
0.051`}, 
{2.523`, -1.446`, 0.051`}, {2.525`, -1.458`, 0.051`}, {2.574`, -1.411`, 0.052`}, 
{2.573`, -1.421`, 0.052`}, {2.555`, -1.422`, 0.051`}, 
{2.54`, -1.424`, 0.051`}, {2.539`, -1.434`, 0.051`}, {2.527`, -1.438`, 0.051`}, 
{2.523`, -1.446`, 0.051`}, {2.525`, -1.458`, 0.051`}, {2.628`, -1.388`, 0.001`}, 
{2.596`, -1.381`, 0.001`}, {2.591`, -1.389`, 0.001`}, {2.573`, -1.39`, 0.001`}, 
{2.565`, -1.396`, 0.001`}, {2.564`, -1.406`, 0.001`}, {2.546`, -1.406`,0.001`}, 
{2.545`, -1.416`, 0.001`}, {2.533`, -1.42`, 0.001`}, {2.522`, -1.424`, 
0.001`}, 
{2.524`, -1.436`, 0.001`}, {2.516`, -1.442`, 0.001`}, {2.508`, -1.448`, 0.001`}, 
{2.504`, -1.456`, 0.001`}, {2.496`, -1.462`, 0.001`}, {2.494`, -1.472`, 
0.001`}, 
{2.486`, -1.477`, 0.001`}, {2.485`, -1.487`, 0.001`}, {2.628`, -1.388`, 0.001`}, 
{2.596`, -1.381`, 0.001`}, {2.591`, -1.389`, 0.001`}, {2.573`, -1.39`, 
0.001`}, 
{2.565`, -1.396`, 0.001`}, {2.564`, -1.406`, 0.001`}, {2.546`, -1.406`, 0.001`}, 
{2.545`, -1.416`, 0.001`}, {2.533`, -1.42`, 0.001`}, {2.522`, -1.424`, 
0.001`}, 
{2.524`, -1.436`, 0.001`}, {2.516`, -1.442`, 0.001`}, {2.508`, -1.448`, 0.001`}, 
{2.504`, -1.456`, 0.001`}, {2.496`, -1.462`, 0.001`}, {2.494`, -1.472`, 
0.001`}, 
{2.486`, -1.477`, 0.001`}, {2.485`, -1.487`, 0.001`}, {2.61`, -1.378`, -0.05`}, 
{2.595`, -1.381`, -0.05`}, {2.58`, -1.383`, -0.05`}, {2.572`, -1.39`, -0.05`}, 
{2.561`, -1.394`, -0.05`}, {2.557`, -1.402`, -0.05`}, {2.549`, -1.408`, -0.05`}, 
{2.544`, -1.416`, -0.05`}, {2.533`, -1.42`, -0.05`}, {2.528`, -1.428`, -0.05`}, 
{2.52`, -1.434`, -0.05`}, {2.512`, -1.44`, -0.049`}, {2.504`, -1.446`, -0.049`}, 
{2.5`, -1.454`, -0.049`}, {2.488`, -1.457`, -0.049`}, {2.487`, -1.467`, -0.049`}, 
{2.483`, -1.475`, -0.049`}, {2.485`, -1.487`, -0.049`}, {2.61`, -1.378`,-0.05`}, 
{2.595`, -1.381`, -0.05`}, {2.58`, -1.383`, -0.05`},{2.572`, -1.39`,-0.05`}, 
{2.561`, -1.394`, -0.05`}, {2.557`, -1.402`, -0.05`}, {2.549`, -1.408`,-0.05`}, 
{2.544`, -1.416`, -0.05`}, {2.533`, -1.42`, -0.05`}, {2.528`, -1.428`,-0.05`}, 
{2.52`, -1.434`, -0.05`}, {2.512`, -1.44`, -0.049`}, {2.504`, -1.446`,-0.049`}, 
{2.5`, -1.454`, -0.049`}, {2.488`, -1.457`, -0.049`}, {2.487`, -1.467`,-0.049`}, 
{2.483`, -1.475`, -0.049`}, {2.485`, -1.487`, -0.049`}, {2.578`, -1.393`,-0.101`}, 
{2.56`, -1.393`, -0.1`}, {2.548`, -1.397`, -0.1`}, {2.544`, -1.405`,-0.1`}, 
{2.536`, -1.411`, -0.1`}, {2.528`, -1.417`, -0.1`}, {2.52`, -1.423`,-0.1`},
{2.516`, -1.431`, -0.1`}, {2.508`, -1.437`, -0.1`}, {2.5`,-1.443`,-0.099`}, 
{2.495`, -1.451`, -0.099`}, {2.494`, -1.461`, -0.1`}, {2.578`, -1.393`,-0.101`}, 
{2.56`, -1.393`, -0.1`}, {2.548`,-1.397`, -0.1`}, {2.544`, -1.405`,-0.1`}, 
{2.536`, -1.411`, -0.1`}, {2.528`, -1.417`, -0.1`}, {2.52`, -1.423`,-0.1`}, 
{2.516`, -1.431`, -0.1`}, {2.508`, -1.437`, -0.1`}, {2.5`, -1.443`,-0.099`}, 
{2.495`, -1.451`, -0.099`}, {2.494`, -1.461`, -0.1`}};

p0 = {x0, y0, z0};
n = {nx, ny, nz};
p = {x, y, z};
u = {ux, uy, uz};
v = {vx, vy, vz};

obj = Sum[((data[[k]] - p0) . n)^2, {k, 1, Length[data]}];
sol = NMinimize[{obj, n . n == 1}, {x0, y0, z0, nx, ny, nz}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

equs = {n . u == 0, n . v == 0, u . v == 0, u . u == 1, v . v == 1, vz == 0} /. sol[[2]];
soluv = Quiet@Solve[equs, {ux, uy, uz, vx, vy, vz}];
barycenter = Total[data]/Length[data];
gr1 = Graphics3D[{Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]}, PlotRange -> All];
gr2 = ContourPlot3D[((p - p0) . n /. sol[[2]]) == 0, {x, 2.4, 2.65}, {y, -1.5, -1.2}, {z, -0.2, 0.1}, ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[0.3]}, Mesh -> None];
gr3 = Graphics3D[{Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[barycenter]}];
r = 0.09;
gr4 = ParametricPlot3D[barycenter + r (u Cos[t] + v Sin[t]) /. soluv[[1]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4]


